# Android Studio Error Output Missing

Tags: android, android-studio, console

I got a problem while creating an app with Android Studio, I can't find a console which shows all errors from the running application, when I'm testing it on my phone. 
My phone force closes the app but Android Studio doesn't show any error or something. The last time I used Android Studio (1/2 year ago) System.out.print did work but now: nothing...
Can someone help me?
Thank you guys!

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for the "Android" view, docked by default towards the left side of the bottom dock bar. It will contain a LogCat pane with logging messages:

[image: LogCat in Android Studio]

When you run an app, this view normally pops up, and it sets a filter (drop-down in the top right of my screenshot) to be for your app's process. If you seem to be missing messages, change it to "No Filters". LogCat sometimes fails to process the per-app filter properly for me, and I am not quite certain why.

Comment: 1. Logcat doesn't show anything; 2. Does ist show things like NullPointer or OverflowError, if it's working?

Comment: @Talexy: Yes, it will show Java stack traces for those. Again, check your filters.

Comment: Every time I click on the run button the filter changes to app: main.game and when I'm change it back to no filters the field stays white

Comment: @Talexy: Correct. If you change that to "No Filters", and your stack traces show up, then you are experiencing the same problems that I am, and I do not have a solution for those just yet.

Comment: @CommonsWare .... I am experiencing the same problem in `3.1.4` android studio ..... Is there a solution for this

Comment: @Devrath: I do not know what exactly you mean by "the same problem". I know of no scenario in which your app crashes ("force closes") and there is no stack trace of any form.

Comment: @CommonsWare .... "the same problem". I am referring to is when the crash happens, Output in the log comes and disappears. And I have tried selecting "Selected Application" in the bottom panel and with filter ...

Comment: @Devrath: Select "No Filters", not "Selected Application", and see if that helps. Or, access LogCat from the command line using `adb logcat`, and see if you can find your stack trace there.